# Key management for JWT encryption (ASP.NET Core 5)

Tags: c#, encryption, jwt

I need some help with the encryption of JWT in ASP.NET Core 5, please. Specifically, this is more about key management, where I'm stuck.

The creation of the tokens is done by the separate WebAPI, while the token validation should be done by the server. Therefore, I need to exchange the keys between both instances. Also, the keys used should rotate at defined intervals. Therefore I added a keystore via `.AddDataProtected()`, which already generates keys and works.

I see three options, and at least two of them are probably wrong (or at least suboptimal):

- **Option 1**: Encrypt all tokens for all users with the current default key in the keystore until it expires (would be easiest to manage if there were no objections from a security point of view).
- **Option 2**: have a separate key created for each user in the keystore (I am unsure if the keystore is meant for this).
- **Option 3**: Generate random keys for each user, then encrypt them with the default key in the keystore, then store them encrypted (difficult to handle, I think).

Maybe there is an option 4 that I am missing. Maybe I'm just source-blind or I've got myself into something because I've been tinkering with it for days now.

Here is the source code excerpt of my SecurityTokenDescriptor:

```cs
SecurityTokenDescriptor tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
{
    // ...
    EncryptingCredentials =
        new EncryptingCredentials(
            new SymmetricSecurityKey(mySecretKey) { KeyId = "MySecretKeyId" },
            SecurityAlgorithms.Aes256KW,
            SecurityAlgorithms.Aes256CbcHmacSha512)
    // ...
};
```

So it is specifically about the EncryptionCredentials, not about the keys for signing.

In my keystore, a default key like this is automatically generated:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<key id="539676e1-708a-4201-a854-f5313664d38b" version="1">
  <creationDate>2021-03-12T06:57:50.60916Z</creationDate>
  <activationDate>2021-03-12T06:57:50.599208Z</activationDate>
  <expirationDate>2021-03-19T06:57:50.599208Z</expirationDate>
  <descriptor deserializerType="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption.ConfigurationModel.AuthenticatedEncryptorDescriptorDeserializer, Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60">
    <descriptor>
      <encryption algorithm="AES_256_CBC" />
      <validation algorithm="HMACSHA512" />
      <encryptedSecret decryptorType="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlDecryptor, Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" xmlns="http://schemas.asp.net/2015/03/dataProtection">
        <encryptedKey xmlns="">
          <!-- This key is encrypted with Windows DPAPI. -->
          <value>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</value>
        </encryptedKey>
      </encryptedSecret>
    </descriptor>
  </descriptor>
</key>
```

If the period of the key expires, the keystore automatically creates a new (default) key for me and keeps the predecessor but additionally for further decryption tasks. However, new requests are created with the new default key from this point on.

I am referring to this [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-management?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Via DataProtection I get two interface groups:

- **IKeyManager** (for managing the key rings of the keystore)
- **IDataProtectionProvider** / **IDataProtector** (encrypt/decrypt data with the default key in the keystore)

This in turn brings me to the above three options. I'm trying to bring all this information together somehow to build a reasonable token workflow that is also practical.

Should I now simply use the default key from the keystore (via IKeyManager) in the EncryptingCredentials of the SecurityTokenDescriptor directly, or should I create a new key for each user/token via IKeyManager.CreateNewKey(). Or just use IDataProtector to secure the token keys with it and store them separately?

I would be very grateful for help of any kind! Thanks!

Comment: To be sure: which keys are we talking about? The encryption key? If so, how does that expire? And what does "default key" refer to? (As opposed to a non-default key)

Comment: Use RSA; only share the private key with issuer; in all other APIs just include public keys.

Re: where to store them it would depend on how/where do you host your APIs. E.g. in Windows you can use Certificate store, on linux a file with correct ACL, on a mac a keychain, and then each cloud service offers their option for storing secrets.

Comment: @Xerillio Thank you. I have made my request a little more specific. I am concerned about the EncryptingCredentials for the encryption of the token. The key is replaced by the keystore provider after a defined span by a successor, currently 7 days. The default key is the currently valid one in the keystore (the newest one).

Comment: @zaitsman Thanks. However, RSA then presents me with the same challenges as described above, right? I then have a key (public/private pair) with which I can then either encrypt all tokens (option 1) or encrypt the "subkeys" that I create separately for each token (option 3). Or just a separate RSA pair per user/token (option 2).

Comment: Its one rsa per service, never per token. If anyone is telling you to do one key per token i think it’s time to question their security acumen

Comment: @zaitsman Okay, I like that a lot. That points to my option 1. Thanks a lot! :-)